Re-invoke a hook in react
I have the following code which uses a third party hook:
const [libraryOptions, setLibraryOptions] = useState<Partial<LibraryOptions>>({
    flag: true
})

const vad = useLibrary(libraryOptions);

When I setLibraryOptions({...libraryOptions, flag:false}) the hook does not update. I want to change these settings for  research purposes however the hook does not expose a way to update these settings.
Is there a way to reinitialise the hook with these new options?

use useEffect hook to reflect the changes.

I'm not familiair with a useLibrary hook, can you link the package name as well? I would check if you can set options on the vad object. Something like vad.setLibraryOptions() if it exists?

or if useLibrary accepts a dependency array. Voting to close for details.

It is https://github.com/ricky0123/vad
AFAIK it does not expose any way of updating settings, I would need to recall it with new arguments. The question applies to any hook realistically, not specifically this one

see: How to handle dependencies array for custom hooks in react for some discussion of dependencies for custom hooks.
